# WebApi GET using Path and Query Parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, get, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core 1.1 API and trying to create an GET api using Path and Query parameters where:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("users/{stationId}/{stationSite}")]
public IActionResult GetUsers(int stationId, int stationSiteid, [FromQuery] Paging properties)...
```

Paging is an Object:

```
public int CurrentIndex {get; set;}
public int ItemsPerPage {get; set;}
```

Now, I need a call like this to work:

```
api/users/1/2?currentIndex=1&itemsPerPage=10
```

The `FromQuery` is not working, it appears on Swagger but does not pass the correct values to API.

Am I missing anything ??

Comment: This should work, I just tested. Is the `Paging` class composed with just those fields? Does it have anything on its constructor? Also, the `stationSite` parameter is misspelled. It has to match with the parameter `stationSiteid`.

Comment: Well it was just an example from my current code. 
I just figured out what was the problem. 
Indeed this approach works well, I have tested on Postman.
The problem were : WebApi were using a Swashbuckle(swagger) version 6.0.0-beta902, that did not recognize the folowing Paging parameter.  Once I updated the Swashbuckle to 4.1.0 it works fine. 
This Swashbucle version  is a Prerelease on NuGet, I just can list it on Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager, but its not related on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/1.1.0 - this caused me confusion. 

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ah, so what it was not working was calling the API from swagger? Got it. Maybe post it as an answer so others can benefit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an prerelease version of Swashbuckle was causing this confusion.

This properties were not listed on Swagger but using Postman to test the API, it worked.

Downgrading Swashbuckle to 4.0.0 stable, worked fine.